# How to I return JSON from a Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

How do I return JSON from a HTTP Google Cloud Function in Python? Right now I have something like:

```
import json

def my_function(request):
    data = ...
    return json.dumps(data)
```

This correctly returns JSON, but the `Content-Type` is wrong (it's `text/html` instead).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Cloud Functions has [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) available under the hood, so you can use it's [`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.json.jsonify) function to return a JSON response.

In your function:

```
from flask import jsonify

def my_function(request):
    data = ...
    return jsonify(data)
```

This will return a `flask.Response` object with the application/json `Content-Type` and your `data` serialized  to JSON.

You can also do this manually if you prefer to avoid using Flask:

```py
import json

def my_function(request):
    data = ...
    return json.dumps(data), 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

Comment: Python has a standard library to deal with json (json.dumps), no need of an external library to do this. In some cases, a simple str(data) do the trick.

Comment: @Oxydron I think you missed the last example I have here.

Comment: Indeed I missed :\, but I think that the only correct answer is that last one you written, because it solves the problem without external libraries.

Comment: I'd suggest adding the dash into 'Content-Type' for the second part of your answer.

Comment: @Oxydron since as Dustin points out, Flask is baked into gcloud functions, I'd argue this doesn't really add a dependency (eg request is a `flask.Request` object), it seems reasonable to make use of the available functionality.  Adding flask to requests isn't actually needed for their example to work, though being explicit about your dependencies is reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

For me, json.dumps() did not work in the cloud function. It worked only in my local server. So, I had to build the json by myself:

```
    headers= {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    id1= "1234567"
    var1= "variable 1"
    text = '{"id1":"'+id1+'","var1":"'+var1+'"}'
    return (text, 200, headers)
```

Comment: Did you `import json`? When you say it didn't work, what error did you get?

Comment: Yes, I imported and tried both json and flask.jsonify. It returned an error "INVALID ARGUMENT" but I was not able to get any information beyond this. I know it was on this line because if I remove it from the code, the error message does not appear.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Flask per se

```
import json

def my_function(request):
    data = ...
    return json.dumps(data), 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}
```

Make 200 whatever response code is suitable, eg. 404, 500, 301, etc.

If you're replying from a HTML AJAX request

```
return json.dumps({'success': True, 'data': data}), 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}
```

to return an error instead for the AJAX request

```
return json.dumps({'error': True}), 404, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this. Using the json module works well enough.

```py
import json

def some_function(request):
    data = 'data_obj'
    return json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Erick K, welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for the answer, and special double-thanks for having tested it before submitting — we are lucky to have you!